# vue-fullscreen is not working inside iframe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using [vue-fullscreen](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-fullscreen) library. And I've implement it on video tag to make video full screen as

```
 <fullscreen ref="fullscreen">
      <video :srcObject.prop="videosource" autoplay playsinline :muted.prop="muted"/>
 </fullscreen>
```

It's working fine. Now I've deployed this app (also working).I created another vue app having iframe tag with src to first deployed app as

```
 <iframe :src="firstAppLink" frameborder="0" allow="microphone; camera"></iframe>
```

Here when click on fullscreen button inside deployed app to make video full screen it is giving console error and full screen not done. Here is image showing error.

[image: Image showing error]

Comment: Any vue expert here in this worlds largest community platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try add attribute `allow="fullscreen"` to the iframe element

Answer (score 0):

You would have to use an eventListner on both ends to pass information on how to handle the fullscreen event